# How to implement $_SESSION to hash login

Tags: php, session, authentication

how to implemented a $_SESSION in a  login page because if the $_SESSION after login page  it s the same to login page the user can see the content of the page

login page

```
<?php include'header.php'; ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
$msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'connessione.php';

$email = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$sql = $connessione->query("SELECT id, password FROM titolare_azienda WHERE email='$email'");

if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
$data = $sql->fetch_array();

if (password_verify($password, $data['password'])) {
$msg = "You have been logged IN! <a href='User/index.php'>vai</a>";
}

else
$msg = "Please check your inputs!";

} else
$msg = "Please check your inputs!";

}

?>

<?php if ($msg != "") echo $msg . "<br><br>"; ?>

<form method="post" action="accesso.php">
<input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email..."><br>
<input class="form-control" minlength="5" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password..."><br>
<input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In"><br>
</form>
```

the $_SESSION it must be "sessione_valida"

code about after login page:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
include("connessione.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['sessione_valida'])) {
$result = mysqli_query($connessione,
"SELECT * FROM utenti");
?>
<!-- end control $_SESSION   -->
<!-- content if the condition it s true   -->
<!-- end content if the condition it s true   -->
<?php
}else{ ?>
<!-- content if the condition it s false   -->

<!-- end content if the condition it s false   -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I see you check `($_SESSION['sessione_valida']` but do you set `($_SESSION['sessione_valida']` ? Within your `if` on `password_verify` you should set this to true

Comment: yes but i dont know how to impelemted a $_SESSION in a login page , infact this is my question

Comment: As long as every page where you want to use `$_SESSION` has `session_start();` in it, all you do is `$_SESSION['sessione_valida'] = true;`

Comment: In the `if` clause, just set the session variable(s) and redirect. Then at the top of this same page after the `session_start();` do something like `if(!empty($_SESSION['sessione_valida'])) { header('Location: /wherever.php'); exit; }` then the user can not return to this page after they have logged in successfully.

Comment: i have implemented what u have write but doesn't work, please guys help me , i not have idea to fix this

Comment: The form is set to POST to `accesso.php`. In that file, you would set your `$_SESSION` variable if the input is correct. Then, redirect to your content page. If the input is incorrect, redirect back to your login page.

Answer (score 0):

guys i want write the answer becuase i fix my problem and in the future 
if for someone it will be useful here is the solution

login page :

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
$messaggio = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'connessione.php';

$email = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);


$sql = $connessione->query("SELECT id, password FROM titolare_azienda WHERE email='$email'");

if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
$data = $sql->fetch_array();

if (password_verify($password, $data['password'])) {
$_SESSION['NAME_SESSION'] = true;   // THIS IS THE SOLUTION
$messaggio = "Accesso effettuato correttamente! <a href='User/index.php'>Accedi alla tua Dashboard</a>";

}
else
$messaggio = "Please check your inputs!";

}

}

?>

<?php if ($messaggio != "") echo $messaggio . "<br><br>"; ?>

<form method="post" action="accesso.php">
<input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email..."><br>
<input class="form-control" minlength="5" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password..."><br>
<input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In"><br>
</form>
```

page after login:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
include("connessione.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['NAME_SESSION'])) {
$result = mysqli_query($connessione,
"SELECT * FROM utenti");
?>
<!-- end control $_SESSION   -->
<!-- content if the condition it s true   -->
<!-- end content if the condition it s true   -->
<?php
}else{ ?>
<!-- content if the condition it s false   -->

<!-- end content if the condition it s false   -->
<?php } ?>
```